# LC3 loop through and test left most bit in a word

Tags: lc3

So I have a word, and I want to loop through and test the left most bit.  I have my word and I'm passing it to my subroutine, I know how to build a loop, I'm just not sure how to test the left most bit in the word.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is with bit masking -- perform a bitwise AND between the word you want to check and a bit mask with a 1 in any position you wish to test.  i.e. in binary:

```
my word:   11
bitmask:   10
         & ==
           10
```

you can see that the 1 in the left side drops out.  So to do something similar on a 16bit number:

```
0x0230 & 0x8000 = 0x0000
0xC020 & 0x8000 = 0x8000 != 0x0000
```

The important thing to note here is that if the bit is not present the AND returns a 0, and if the bit is present it returns something else.  It doesn't matter what it is, just that it's not zero.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it applies to your specific task but a simple approach could be performing a logical/arithmetic left shift to the word. This is simply done by adding the word to itself (which is equal to multiplying by 2 and thus shifting all the bits to the left 1 "spot). After doing this, the condition codes will be set (assuming you're using the GPRs) and you can test if the left most bit is a 1 or a 0 by checking if the shifted word is positive OR zero (hence the left most bit is a 0), or negative (hence the left most bit is a 1). Loop over the whole word following this approach and you'll be able to determine the value of each bit in your word. Hope this helps.